# CSS style cumbersome to clean and less code

Tags: css

Hey all i have some CSS code like so:

```
/* ROW 1 (1-8) */
#rsvpBadge0{position: absolute; top: -2px; left: -1px; z-index: 2; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
#rsvpBadge1{position: absolute; top: -2px; left: 74px; z-index: 2; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
#rsvpBadge2{position: absolute; top: -2px; left: 149px; z-index: 2; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
#rsvpBadge3{position: absolute; top: -2px; left: 224px; z-index: 2; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
#rsvpBadge4{position: absolute; top: -2px; left: 299px; z-index: 2; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
#rsvpBadge5{position: absolute; top: -2px; left: 374px; z-index: 2; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
#rsvpBadge6{position: absolute; top: -2px; left: 449px; z-index: 2; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
#rsvpBadge7{position: absolute; top: -2px; left: 524px; z-index: 2; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
/* ROW 2 (9-16) */
#rsvpBadge8{position: absolute; top: 68px; left: -1px; z-index: 2; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
#rsvpBadge9{position: absolute; top: 68px; left: 74px; z-index: 2; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
#rsvpBadge10{position: absolute; top: 68px; left: 149px; z-index: 2; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
#rsvpBadge11{position: absolute; top: 68px; left: 224px; z-index: 2; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
#rsvpBadge12{position: absolute; top: 68px; left: 299px; z-index: 2; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
#rsvpBadge13{position: absolute; top: 68px; left: 374px; z-index: 2; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
#rsvpBadge14{position: absolute; top: 68px; left: 449px; z-index: 2; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
#rsvpBadge15{position: absolute; top: 68px; left: 524px; z-index: 2; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
```

etc etc....

Now i have this the same way going from 1 to 207. It works but the problem i am seeing is it looks fine in FireFox (the top and left coordinates are spot on) but when i view it in IE and Chrome, they are a little off of the top value (needs to be raised a little bit more)

So my question to you all is:

1) How can i shorten the code knowing that each rsvpBadge has a different number and top value?

2) Correct the coordinates for IE and chrome without having to make 3 more 1-209 layers for each browser.

**Here is a visual**

[image]

On the left is what it looks like in Chrome and on the right, FireFox.

Comment: you can use loop but that will need php or javascript

Comment: To get rid of cross browser inconsistencies, use a reset CSS:http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: http://phrogz.net/css/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html

Comment: @xbonez comment is the answer to part B

Comment: Why must you be positioned absolutely? Have you considered restructuring your document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Floating these elements seems appropriate:

```
.rsvp-badge{z-index: 2; width: 50px; height: 50px;float:left;}
```

After that is done, add `clear:left;` to every element that begins a row.

Even better: place all elements in a container of a fixed width so that every row fits 8 elements each.

### Update:

A-ha! So *that's* what an rsvp-badge is supposed to be.

You'd get away with a couple rule [using pseudo-elements](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/7WF3Q/):

```
<div class="user-photo has-rsvpd"></div>
<div class="user-photo"></div>

.user-photo {
    /*size,background etc. ommited*/
    position:relative;/*to allow position:absolude on pseudo-element*/
}
.has-rsvpd:after {
     /*size,background etc. ommited*/
     content:"";position:absolute;top:0;left:0;/*apply to top left corner*/
}
```

Or [restructuring HTML a bit](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/7WF3Q/1/) (which, depending on archtecture, could be appropriate at runtime):

```
<div class="user-photo has-rsvpd"><span class="rsvp-badge"></span></div>
<div class="user-photo"><span class="rsvp-badge"></span></div>

.rsvp-badge {
     display:none;/*hide when user has not rsvpd*/
}
.has-rsvpd .rsvp-badge{
     /*same as :after in the sample above, but without a content property*/
}
```

Comment: You approach does not work. It needs to be absolute or it moves the image from being on top of it to being next to it.

Comment: @StealthRT: what is "it"? on top of "what"? please commit the effort of uploading a sample to jsfiddle

Comment: @stealthrt: Have you considered making the image as a background?

Comment: @Truth: It needs to be over the image.. its a banner image.

Answer (score 1):

**If you don't want to use javascript or floating**, can you change the html? Then add classes to the elements because (instead of ids) classes don't have to be unique, e.g.:

```
<div class="rsvpBadgeAll rsvpBadgeLeft0 rsvpBadgeTop0">...</div>
<div class="rsvpBadgeAll rsvpBadgeLeft1 rsvpBadgeTop0">...</div>
...
<div class="rsvpBadgeAll rsvpBadgeLeft7 rsvpBadgeTop0">...</div>
<div class="rsvpBadgeAll rsvpBadgeLeft0 rsvpBadgeTop1">...</div>
...
<div class="rsvpBadgeAll rsvpBadgeLeft7 rsvpBadgeTop1">...</div>
...
```

And also define the css with classes instead of ids, e.g.:

```
.rsvpBadgeAll { position: absolute; z-index: 2; width: 50px; height: 50px; }

.rsvpBadgeLeft0 { left: -1px; }
.rsvpBadgeLeft1 { left: 74px; }
.rsvpBadgeLeft2 { left: 149px; }
.rsvpBadgeLeft3 { left: 224px; }
.rsvpBadgeLeft4 { left: 299px; }
.rsvpBadgeLeft5 { left: 374px; }
.rsvpBadgeLeft6 { left: 449px; }
.rsvpBadgeLeft7 { left: 524px; }

.rsvpBadgeTop0 { top: -2px; }
.rsvpBadgeTop1 { top: 68px; }
.rsvpBadgeTop2 { top: ...px; }
...
.rsvpBadgeTop25 { top: ...px; }
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting the HTML change. However there is probably a better solution than using position absolute.

Comment: My answer is for question 1) (reducing the css code). For question 2) Have you seen xbonez comment? Have you tried adding the reset css?

Comment: @scessor: Resetting it made it look like it does in Chrome no matter what browser.

Comment: @scessor: Shouldnt it be: **rsvpBadgeAll rsvpBadgeLeft0 rsvpBadgeTop0** - **rsvpBadgeAll rsvpBadgeLeft7 rsvpBadgeTop0** then **rsvpBadgeAll rsvpBadgeLeft0 rsvpBadgeTop1** - **rsvpBadgeAll rsvpBadgeLeft7 rsvpBadgeTop1** etc etc?

Comment: After resetting you have the same behavior in all browsers? That's great. Now you have to find what is creating the "padding". Absolute position searches the nearest positioned ancestor. Can you show us the html and other css definitions or do you have a link to your site?

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you can put only

```
    #rsvpBadge{position: absolute; z-index: 2; width: 50px; height: 50px;}

    #rsvpBadge0{ top:<x>, left:<x>}
    #rsvpBadge1{ top:<x>, left:<x>}
    #rsvpBadge2{ top:<x>, left:<x>}
```

........and so on
And write a javascript for calculating the top and left as per screen size.

Comment: Put a common class on all, or some other (correct) css selector.

Comment: An element may only have one ID and that ID is also unique to the entire document. For what you are trying to achieve you must use a class name.